# Long-term storage of a gas?

Tags: pressure, design, pressure-vessel

Can this formula be used to evaluate the minimum thickness of a spherical pressure vessel that holds hydrogen gas at 10 ATM for a long time?

$$\sigma = \dfrac{p r}{2 t}$$

I was told, "As long as you don't need to hold the pressure for a long time or above room temperature, which will cause creep." It would seem that the person is trying to say that the container will fail over time due to creep. Is this true if the container will never go above room temperature? If yes, how should the design of the container change to address this problem?

Comment: what do the letters in the formula mean? please check if the formatting of the formula is ok.

Comment: In addition to what mart asked - this isn't really answerable without more information about the gas and the container. Please [edit] to add more information, and to explain what the exact problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Loss of gas is almost always due to leaks or perfusion.  Loss due to catastrophic container failure is rather unlikely.

Comment: The post was fixed.